# Receiving conditional operator expected error in bash

Tags: bash

Please excuse this extremely inefficient script, I am new to shell scripting. I am receiving an error near the if clause in the function matchFS(). I have posted the error down below. Can anyone offer me some guidance?

```
 #!/bin/bash

function matchFS() {

usage=$(df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
usagearr=( $usage )
for i in "${usagearr[@]}"
do
        if [[ $1 eq "${usagearr[$i]}" ]]; then
        # print matching row from df -h
        fi
done

}

usage=$(df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
usagearr=( $usage )
len=${#usagearr[@]}

for (( i=0; i<$len; i++ )) # we have to use (( )) here to represent the c style for loop
do
        if [ "${usagearr[$i]}" -gt "10" ]; then
                matchFS ${usagearr[$i]}
        fi
done
```

Error: line 13: conditional binary operator expected
line 13: syntax error near `eq'
line 13:`          if [[ $1 eq "49 ]]; then'

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

function matchFS() {

 ### duplicate definition, these are already known to the function.
usage=$(df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g') 
usagearr=( $usage )
### you probably did want to use another variable here,
###  because the "i" is also shared with the caller
for i in "${usagearr[@]}"
do
 ### -eq instead of eq
        if [[ $1 -eq "${usagearr[$i]}" ]]; then
 ### the if statement can not be empty
    # print matching row from df -h
    fi
done
}

usage=$(df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
usagearr=( $usage )
len=${#usagearr[@]}
for (( i=0; i<$len; i++ )) # we have to use (( )) here to represent the c style for loop
do
        if [ "${usagearr[$i]}" -gt "10" ]; then
                matchFS ${usagearr[$i]}
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `help test` you'll quickly realize that `eq` is not one of the choices. At least, not without adding something else to it.

Comment: But I want to compare numbers, not strings. Is the quoting incorrect or something?

Comment: Have you looked at it yet?